# How to show F(0) = 0

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Please help me to find that the  ONLY real solution of $F(x) = 2x / (1 - x^2)$ is x = 0

This is a step in [Additional formula for tangent function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1099663/212507)

Context: An answer to the above says:

Hint: Let $F(0)=x$, then $x=F(0)=2x/(1−x^2)$  But why $F(0) = x$ why not 1 or $x^2$ ?

Now, find the real solutions of $x = 2x/(1−x^2)$.

O.K. so I see 0 is a solution, is it the ONLY real solution? 
Plot $y= x$ and $2x/(1−x^2)$ and note intersection ?

Further Context. This is what I want is to understand: [To get addition formula of $\tan (x)$ via analytic methods](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/292125/212507)

Let  $ϕ(x,h)$be $tan(x)+tan(h)/(1−tan(x) tan(h))$, you can verify ϕ satisfies the same ODE d/dx $y(x)=1+y(x)^2$ like tan(x). Since $ϕ(x,h)=tan(x+h)$ at $x=0$, you can use the fundamental theorem of ODE (in particular, the uniqueness part of solution to an ODE ) to conclude ϕ(x,h)=tan(x+h)$ – achille hui Feb 1 '13 at 15:16 (sorry if not copied properly.)

Comment: **hint:** there are no zero divisors in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @MichaelFreimann I'm not sure that's particularly helpful for an algebra-precalculus tagged question; I wouldn't expect the OP to know what a zero divisor was at this level.

Comment: Do you mean *root*? Asking for the *solution* of $F(x)=\frac{2x}{1-x^2}$ is meaningless without a definition of $F(x)$. However, given that that is the definition of $F(x)$, then we can ask for the root of $F(x)$; that is the $x$ so that $F(x)=0$.

Comment: There has been a question about my level of understanding, I gained BSc Hons in Pure Mathematics 30 years ago, I have forgotten more than I remember. Thank you for all comments. Please tell me if I need to do any more to un block question.

Comment: @Michael Freimann The motivation for this inquiry is that I need help  in A.C. Dixon: Elementary properties of Elliptic Functions. He finds addition formulae for Cos and Sin by analysis which I fully understood. Then with the very first question: do the same for Tan(u+v) in terms of tan(u) , tan(v). Given $ tan'(u) = 1 + tan^2(u)$ and tan(0) = 0

Comment: @xatabay ok, I see it after you have edited the question, but the question seems to be about elementary things, nothing to deal with what you ask further.

Answer (score 2):

One [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1099666/61216) to linked question deals with solutions of
$$x=\frac{2x}{1-x^2}.$$
Assuming $x\ne \pm 1$ this gives the cubic equation
$$0=x(1-x^2)-2x = -x -x^3= -x(1+x^2)$$
with the three roots $x=0\;$ or $x=\pm i$.
Therefore the real solution is $x=0$.

Comment: Why do you think that the question is asking about $F(x)=x$?

Comment: Just follow the link by the OP: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1099663/additional-formula-for-tangent-function

Comment: I don't understand what this answer has to do with the (first line of the) question, where one asks about the roots of $\dfrac {2x} {1-x^2} = 0$.

Comment: Thank you @gammatester we are on the same page.

Comment: So, the justification for assuming x is not +/- 1 is that $R$ has no zero dividers as  @Michael Freimann remarks.

Answer (score 0):

(Assuming you mean "root" by "solution".)

Firstly, $0$ is a solution, as you can check by the fact that $$\frac{2 \times 0}{1 - 0^2} = 0$$

Now, if $\frac{2x}{1-x^2} = 0$, then (multiplying both sides by $\frac{1-x^2}{2}$) you can obtain the requirement that $x=0$.